# Cannot allocate memory при получении списка файлов в директории

Tags: lua

В скрипте имеется такой код:

```lua
local pfile, err = popen("ls -a " .. directory .. "")
if pfile == nil then print(err) end
```

Цель скрипта получить содержимое директории для дальнейшей работы
При запуске скрипта popen возвращает "Cannot allocate memory"
Вопрос следующий, как с этим бороться? Как повлиять на ошибку и есть ли способы "увеличить" память? Скрипт используется в embedded, однако на устройстве есть достаточно памяти.

Comment: думаю вопрос к lua не имеет отношения, это больше относится к системе, погуглите, как увеличить swap file, или что-то связанное с pipe open тоже в самой системе.. возможно еще можно увеличить константу OPEN_MAX указывающую максимальное число дескрипторов в системе (командой ulimit или функцией setrlimit)

Comment: Появление ошибки зависит от кол-ва файлов в директории?  Если да, то используйте тот же лс, но с опцией, отменяющей сортировку файлов перед отображением.  также можно применить фильтр на какой-нибудь поддиапазон (по дате и т.п.), чтобы уменьшить кол-во файлов, возвращаемых за 1 раз.  т.е., будете вызывать её несколько раз и обрабатывать по кусочкам